# A drop of liquid of diameter 2.8 mm breaks up into 125 identical drops. The change in energy is nearly (S.T. of liquid = 75 × 10-3 N/m)

Tags: homework-and-exercises

A drop of liquid of diameter 2.8 mm breaks up into 125 identical drops. The change in energy is nearly

(S.T. of liquid = 75 × 10-3 N/m)

Comment: Hi Selva and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\Delta E = ST.\Delta A$, where $\Delta A$ is the change in surface area. Now, proceed from there.

Comment: Hi Ishan. Please don't answer homework questions. Thanks :-)